# Getting Error "Audience list must have at least 1 item for JWT Authorizer (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2"

Tags: aws-cdk

Am trying to create a HTTPUserPoolAuthoriser using AWS CDK v2. the code is as follows

```
const userpoolIntegration = new HttpLambdaIntegration('Integration', privateLambda);
const userPool = new UserPool(this, "TestUserPool");

const httpUserPoolAuthorizer = new HttpUserPoolAuthorizer('UserPoolAuthorizer', userPool, {
      authorizerName: 'User-Pool-Authorizer',
      identitySource: ['method.request.header.Authorization'],
      userPoolClients: ["34qvm73vj4bvlfr3da5ugunebc"],
      userPoolRegion: 'ap-south-1',
      
    });
```

and this is attached to the apigatway using the following code:

```
api.addRoutes({
      integration: userpoolIntegration,
      path: '/user',
      methods: [apigatewayv2.HttpMethod.POST],
      authorizer: httpUserPoolAuthorizer,
      
    })
```

when we try to execute it using `cdk deploy`, am getting the following error

`"Audience list must have at least 1 item for JWT Authorizer (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2"`

most of the code here is from the code from the AWS CDK documentation.

what is strange is it is trying to use JWT Authorizer.

let me know if anyone has any clue!

Answer (score 0):

UserPoolClient.userPoolClientId is what ends up in JWTAuthorizers' `audience`:

```
jwtAudience: this.props.userPoolClients.map((c) => c.userPoolClientId)
```

([source](https://github.com/TikiTDO/aws-cdk/blob/266112931b8e7ac4b1039b442c6568a902c11aa6/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers/lib/http/user-pool.ts#L59)).

You'll need to provide a [UserPoolClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito.UserPoolClient.html) object, instead of just providing that clientId as a bare string as you do now. Try

```
const client = userPool.addClient(... //your setup...);
```